# About java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate : how frequently it executes task?

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I was looking at javadoc of -->  `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`

I have re-produced below the javadoc:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and **subsequently with the given period; that is executions will commence after initialDelay then initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on.** If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor. If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

```
Parameters:
command the task to execute

initialDelay the time to delay first execution

period the period between successive executions

unit the time unit of the initialDelay and period parameters
Returns:
a ScheduledFuture representing pending completion of the task, and whose get() method will throw an exception upon cancellation
```

I understood that first time it would be enabled after `initialDelay` and then repeated after `period`.  However, looking at **highlighted** section above, it seems frequency is increasing in-between the successive executions.

Is this the correct behaviour? If so, then the delay would get increased from previous executions?

Can anyone help clarify?

Comment: I don't know hwy you think the frequency is increasing. It just says that the point of time when it will executed is relative to the delay. If you have a delay of 10s, then you can compute the time of each execution with just always taking into account the initial delay. So if you have 5s as period, then the first call is after 10s (delay + 0 * period), the second call after 15s (delay + 1 * period), 20s, ...

Comment: delay is just the initial point in time when everything starts

Comment: `initialPeriod = 10s`, `duration = 5s`, `now = 21:50:00`. it starts at `21:50:10`, next run is on `21:50:15`, next run is on `21:50:20`, then `21:50:25` (_or_ 5 * 3 + 10 for seconds). what is not clear?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification , I got what the documentation is trying to convey. Best Regards